# How to address Cypress (cy.type() can only be called on a single element.) error?

Tags: cypress

I have three input fields:

```
      cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .input-module_input__3wsvS').should('be.visible').type(foo)
      cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .input-module_input__3wsvS').should('be.visible').type(bar)
      cy.get(':nth-child(3) > .input-module_input__3wsvS').should('be.visible').type(foo-bar)
```

How to I get my test to pass? I am using css modules in react. ID-Tags don't seem to work, so any other suggestions?

.first() is ok to identify the 1st, but how would I address the 2nd and 3rd input?

Comment: Can you include the HTML for the site being tested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful using the "hash" the originates from frontend websites who use css-modules as any change to the underlying css will change its value and therefore break the tests.

Similarly the more complicated a selector is the more surface area there is for change in the structure of the document to break the test.

.eq() is how you select children by index (0 based) you can find the documentation here:

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq

For projects using css modules i'd suggest using the "starts with" selector

```
cy.get(`[class^='${cls}']`))
```

// or add the following command for "partial class" to make writing it easier

```
Cypress.Commands.add('pclass', (cls) => cy.get(`[class^='${cls}']`));
```

usage in your example:

```
cy.get(`[class^='input-module_input']`).eq(1) // (for second child)
// or (After you've added the command)
cy.pclass("input-module_input").eq(1); // (for second child that mathes)
```

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. It has also solved the issue of css modules which I was going to address later today!

Comment: How would you refactor this to match with the 'starts with' selector?

cy.get(':nth-child(2) > :nth-child(2) > .inputmodule_input__3wsvS').type('foo')

cy.get(':nth-child(2) > :nth-child(3) > .inputmodule_input__3wsvS').type('bar')

cy.get(':nth-child(2) > :nth-child(4) > .input-module_input__3wsvS').type('foofoobar')

cy.get(':nth-child(2) > :nth-child(5) > .input-module_input__3wsvS').type('barbarfoo')

Comment: @ERLay, impossible to say without seeing the "structure" of the HTML.
https://gist.github.com/ShanonJackson/1f0084c97c94ef547a7d8ee8c3ca62d6

Comment: Thanks!, solved it by using .eq where needed.

Answer (score 1):

Using `.eq()` might give you better results

```js
cy.get('.input-module_input__3wsvS').eq(0).should('be.visible').type('foo')
cy.get('.input-module_input__3wsvS').eq(1).should('be.visible').type('bar')
```